# Lipschitz continuity of function on convex and bounded set; Andersson, Böiers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions, chain-rule

I'm reading Ordinary Differential Equations by Andersson and Böiers. There is a Lemma regarding Lipschitz continuity which I have some questions about. $\pmb f$ is a vector-valued function, and $\pmb x,\pmb y$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that depend on $t$.

> **Lemma.** Assume that $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex and bounded set, and that the function $\pmb{f}$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$. Then $\pmb{f}$ is Lipschitz continuous in $\Omega$.

> **Proof.** The line segment between two points $(t,\pmb{x})$ and $(t,\pmb{y})$ in $\Omega$ is contained in $\Omega$ by the assumption of convexity. Hence \begin{align} \pmb{f}(t,\pmb{x})-\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y})&=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))\mathrm{d}s \tag1 \\ &=\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial x_i}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))(x_i-y_i)\mathrm{d}s,\tag2\end{align} by the chain rule. Set $K=\max_i\sup_{\Omega}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right|$ (which exists by assumption). Then \begin{equation}|\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{x})-\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y})|\leq\int_0^1 nK|\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}|\mathrm{d}s=nK|\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}|.\tag3 \end{equation}

1. I do not understand exactly how the convexity is being used. That $\Omega$ is convex means that $\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y})\in\Omega$ for $s\in [0,1]$. Geometrically, what does it mean to integrate the function $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))$ over $[0,1]$? Is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))$ well-defined?
2. I'd be very grateful if someone could clarify how we obtain $(2)$ from the chain rule. I'm familiar with $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s},\tag4$$ where $z = z(x(t,s), y(t,s) )$, but here it seems like we have a vector valued function which depends on $s$ in a slightly unusual way.
3. Small detail maybe, but I'm a bit confused about the notation $f$ in $\max_i\sup_{\Omega}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right|$. The authors have been using $\pmb f$ to denote the function. Would it be incorrect to replace $f$ by $\pmb f$ here?

Comment: Convexity is used to make sure that there is a straight line between $x,y$.

Comment: @copper.hat why do we need a straight line between $x,y$?

Comment: The integration in (1) is along the straight line $y + s(x-y)$ for $s \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof should mention that we fix $t$, and thus $(t,\pmb x)$ and $(t,\pmb y)$ are two fixed points in $\Omega$.

1. The function $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))$ is well-defined since, as shown in 2, it can be evaluated using the chain rule, and the derivatives exist and are bounded on $\Omega$ since $\pmb f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$. Convexity in this proof is necessary since the function is being integrated over the line connecting $(t,\pmb x)$ and $(t,\pmb y)$.
2. The function can be viewed as a composition of $\pmb f$ with $\pmb{g}_t(s)=(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))$. The subscript denotes that $t$ is held fixed. We could omit the subscript $t$ and only write $\pmb{g}(s)$. The derivative of $D\pmb{f}\circ \pmb{g}(s)$ is given by the chain rule; $D\pmb{f}(\pmb{g}(s))D\pmb{g}(s)$, where
   \begin{align}
       D\pmb{f}(\pmb{g}(s))&=\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)} &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_1}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_n}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)} \\
           \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
           \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial t}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)} & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial z_1}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial z_n}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)},
       \end{bmatrix}, \\   D\pmb{g}(s)&=\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\(x_1-y_1) \\ \vdots \\ (x_n-y_n)
       \end{bmatrix}.
   \end{align}
   So
   \begin{align}
       D\pmb{f}(\pmb{g}(s))D\pmb{g}(s)&=\begin{bmatrix}
           \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_j}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)}(x_j-y_j) \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial z_j}\Bigr|_{\pmb{g}(s)}(x_j-y_j)
       \end{bmatrix}\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial z_j}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))
       (x_j-y_j).
   \end{align}
3. $f$ is most likely a typo here for $\pmb{f}$. $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. For this norm, we have $|x_i-y_i|\leq |\pmb x-\pmb y|$. Moreover, using $\left|\int_a^b \pmb{f}(s)\mathrm{d}s\right|\le\int_a^b\left|\pmb{f}(s)\right|\mathrm{d}s$ and the triangle inequality, we have
   \begin{align}
       |\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{x})-\pmb{f}(t,\pmb{y})|&\leq \int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial z_i}(t,\pmb{y}+s(\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}))\right|\left|(x_i-y_i) \right| \mathrm{d}s  \\
      &\leq \int_0^1 nK\left|\pmb x-\pmb y \right|\mathrm{d}s \\
      &=nK|\pmb{x}-\pmb{y}|
   \end{align}

Note, a function $f$ is bounded on a set $A$ if $\sup_A |f|$ is finite. A continuous function is bounded on a compact set, therefor $K$ exists.